# Haskell, problems matching types between an instance and a type class

Tags: haskell, image-processing, types, monads

I was trying to do some image processing by converting a list of integers to a vector of pixels (which has the same underlying values but in different types) based on an existing library [JuicyPixels](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/JuicyPixels-3.3.5).

But when I tried to make my `pixel`s an image, an error happened: the pixel has type `Pixel8`, which is an instance of the type class `Pixel px`, but ghci told me that it could not match these types:

```
    ? Couldn't match type ‘px’ with ‘Pixel8’
      ‘px’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          makeListImg :: forall px.
                         Pixel px =>
                         Int -> Int -> [Int] -> Image px
        at src\ImageHandling.hs:63:1-69
      Expected type: T.MutableImage s Pixel8 -> ST s (Image px)
        Actual type: T.MutableImage (PrimState (ST s)) px
                     -> ST s (Image px)
    ? In the second argument of ‘(>>=)’, namely ‘T.unsafeFreezeImage’
      In the expression:
        makeListMutableImg (w, h) (lst2px8 lst) >>= T.unsafeFreezeImage
      In an equation for ‘img’:
          img
            = makeListMutableImg (w, h) (lst2px8 lst) >>= T.unsafeFreezeImage
    ? Relevant bindings include
        img :: ST s (Image px) (bound at src\ImageHandling.hs:66:11)
        makeListImg :: Int -> Int -> [Int] -> Image px
          (bound at src\ImageHandling.hs:64:1)
   |
66 |           img = makeListMutableImg (w, h) (lst2px8 lst) >>= T.unsafeFreezeImage
   |                                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

My codes are (starting from line 63):

```
makeListImg :: forall px. Pixel px => Int -> Int -> [Int] -> Image px
makeListImg w h lst = runST img
    where img :: ST s (Image px)
          img = makeListMutableImg (w, h) (lst2px8 lst) >>= T.unsafeFreezeImage

lst2px8 :: [Int] -> [Pixel8]
lst2px8 = map toPixel8

makeListMutableImg :: forall m px. (Pixel px, PrimMonad m) => (Int, Int) -> [px] -> m (T.MutableImage (PrimState m) px)
makeListMutableImg (w, h) lst = T.MutableImage w h `liftM` vec
    where elemSize = T.componentCount (undefined :: px)
          vec = do
            arr <- M.new (w * h * elemSize)
            let drawLineFromList :: Int -> Int -> [px] -> m ()
                drawLineFromList _ y _ | y >= h = return ()
                drawLineFromList idx y list = column idx 0 list
                    where column :: Int -> Int -> [px] -> m ()
                          column i x l | x >= w = drawLineFromList i (y+1) l
                          column i x l@(head:tail) = do
                              T.unsafeWritePixel arr i head
                              column (i+elemSize) (x+1) tail
            drawLineFromList 0 0 lst
            return arr
```

Those are a lot of codes and I'm really sorry about that, but I don't have a very clear idea of what I am doing; I'm just following the idea in the [library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/JuicyPixels-3.3.5/docs/src/Codec.Picture.Types.html#generateImage).

There are so many monads and abstract layers in the function, so I don't really know where I should focus on. I wanted to copy the list to the mutable vector in `MutableImage` and then use `unsafeFreezeImage` and `runST` to convert it to an `Image px`, but the types stoped me. What should I do now and how could I solve this problem?

Comment: `forall px` means that your code must work with any `px` the _caller_ of your function might choose, which might be something different from `Pixel8`. If you only cover the case `px=Pixel8` don't promise "all `px`es" in your type, use `Pixel8` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best approach here is to construct the `Image` directly.  It's just a regular data type:

```
data Image a = Image { imageWidth :: !Int
                     , imageHeight :: !Int
                     , imageData :: Vector (PixelBaseComponent a) }
```

where `Vector` is from `Data.Vector.Storable`.

For an `ImageRGB8`, the `PixelBaseComponent ImageRGB8` is `Word8`, and the `Vector Word8` is arranged in row-major order with consecutive per-pixel components.  Judging from your code, this is how your `[Int]` is already arranged, so your `makeListImg` function should be as simple as:

```
import Codec.Picture
import qualified Data.Vector.Storable as VS

makeListImg :: Int -> Int -> [Int] -> Image PixelRGB8
makeListImg w h = Image w h . VS.fromList . map fromIntegral
```

I can't imagine an application where a polymorphic version of `makeListImg` would be useful, but it's possible to define something like:

```
unsafeMakeListImg :: (Integral (PixelBaseComponent p), VS.Storable (PixelBaseComponent p))
  => Int -> Int -> [Int] -> Image p
unsafeMakeListImg w h = Image w h . VS.fromList . map fromIntegral
```

which will be general enough for all image formats with integral pixel components.  The problem with trying to use it (and the reason I've called it "unsafe") is that the inferred type for `p` will determine the validity of the structure of the supplied list `[Int]`.  The original `makeListImg` is unsafe, too, but at least it's unsafe in a predictable manner -- you know that the required `[Int]` argument is always data for an `Image PixelRGB8`.

A standalone example:

```
import Codec.Picture
import qualified Data.Vector.Storable as VS

makeListImg :: Int -> Int -> [Int] -> Image PixelRGB8
makeListImg w h = Image w h . VS.fromList . map fromIntegral

main = do
  -- make a left-to-right red gradient
  let foo = makeListImg 100 100 $ concat [[156+x,0,0] | x <- [0..99], y <- [0..99]]
  saveJpgImage 75 "foo.jpg" $ ImageRGB8 foo
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I would try to redefine my function in your way